# jQuery Mobile 1.4 rewriting search <input> tag inappropriately

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, jquery-mobile, search

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div id="search-panel">
    <form>
        <input id="input-catalog-search" name="catlogSearchValue" data-type="search" placeholder="Search...">
    </form>
</div>
```

When I run the code and inspect it in firebug the result is this:

```
<div id="search-panel">
    <form>
         <div class="ui-input-search ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear">
             <input placeholder="Search..." data-type="search" name="catlogSearchValue" id="input-catalog-search">
             <a class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-input-clear-hidden" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" href="#" title="Clear text">Clear text</a>
         </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This wouldn't be a huge deal, except that this mobile web site is going to be heavily used on the iPad and the lack of HTML `type="search"` is causing the keyboard not to display the blue search button and other non-search-specific behavior.

I tried to hardcode `type="search"` into the HTML but jQuery Mobile rewrites the `<input>` as `type="text"` if I do that.

I've also tried modifying the type with jQuery `prop()` after the page loads but that's not triggering the search button either.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

> **Note**: jQM replaces type `search` with `text` to hide *native clear button*. If you still want to show "Search" button, you will have to hide *native clear button* for search input using CSS.

`.prop("type", "search")` should work if you call it at the right moment. For example, you shouldn't call it on `ready()` and refrain from using it. Instead, use pagecontainer events.

If you do the following it will work, however, note that you need also to add `action` and `method` attributes to `form`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
  $("inputID").prop("type", "search");
});
```

After all widgets are created, `pagecreate` event is triggered. You can also use `pagecontainershow` as it fires when the page is visible.

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/o4run2qj/1)